# Network discovery on Windows 7 in 2003 Domain

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, windows-domain

My company is currently using Windows Server 2003, and all computers are configured to use it as their domain controller.

My major concern is when I look for other computers from `File Explorer` > `Networks`. I see only a handful of computers. How do I see all of them?

Most of the computers in the network are running Windows 7 with about 2 - 3 running Windows XP. I've tried turning off the firewall as well as the anti-virus software. The network discovery is turned on, yet, there is no luck.

**NOTE**:
On reading some other articles, I've also verified that NetBIOS is enabled too.

Comment: How PCs are you running on this domain?

Comment: Approximately 40

Comment: Depending on NetBIOS broadcasting to locate computers is spotty at best.  Perhaps look into implementing a [WINS server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784180(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: How many of those PCs are in the same subnet as your PC?

Comment: All of them are in the same subnet.